# vb.net event declaration - adding nonserialized attribution

Tags: vb.net

I'm adding a vb.net assembly to existing c# application.
All of my vb.net types inherit from:

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class BaseObject Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged as PropertyChangedEventHandler

    'Other helper methods'
End Class
```

My problem is that the event can not be serialized.  In c# code, the event is declared like this:

```
 [field: NonSerialized]
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

But I can not see how to do this in any way with vb.net.   Is there extended event declaration that I can use to make the event not serialize?  Or other attribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Visual Basic 10 (as shipped with Visual Studio 2010), you can add the [`NonSerializedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) to the event, just like you would in C#. For example:

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class BaseObject Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    <NonSerialized()> _
    Public Event PropertyChanged as PropertyChangedEventHandler

    'Other helper methods'
End Class
```

Otherwise, things get a little more difficult. You have to do all of the legwork yourself instead of just leaving it to the compiler. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/serializevbclasses.aspx) for more details and step-by-step implementation suggestions.

Comment: Upgrading to 2010 is available, but thanks to you for both information!

Answer (score 3):

Versions earlier than VB10 requires declaring the event with the *Custom* keyword so you can apply the attribute to the private backing field.  That looks like this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
...
    <NonSerialized()> _
    Private propchanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler

    Public Custom Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler
        <MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)> _
        AddHandler(ByVal value As PropertyChangedEventHandler)
            propchanged = DirectCast([Delegate].Combine(propchanged, value), PropertyChangedEventHandler)
        End AddHandler
        <MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)> _
        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As PropertyChangedEventHandler)
            propchanged = DirectCast([Delegate].Remove(propchanged, value), PropertyChangedEventHandler)
        End RemoveHandler
        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
            Dim handler = propchanged
            If handler IsNot Nothing Then handler(sender, e)
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event
```